# trouble with v7-appcompat after export / import in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, export

I am having some trouble after i did a archive file export of my project and the android-support-v7-appcompat projects that I am working on.  I am doing this so i can move the project back and forth between my work computer (Mac) and my home computer (Ubuntu).

The problem that I am encountering is that when i do an import > import existing android code into workspace, the code all gets imported but my project is not recognizing the inclusion of the android-support-v7-appcompat, so i have errors about ActionBarActivity not being defined, etc..

How can i just simply include the appcompat library so that i can move this project between my work and home computers with just the archive zip file?  Thanks

Comment: simply change android Library properties of your project

Comment: sorry, would you clarify that a bit please?

Comment: please check http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject